# Why use "!" after "#" in URL?

Tags: seo, url, javascript, hash

I am working on a project where my landing page URLs will be generated dynamically.

I keep hearing that I have to use `!` after `#` in URLs that are generated dynamically, for SEO reasons.

But no one seems to know WHY. Can anyone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 2):

The `#!` indication in the URL was used to indicate Google that this section of the page appears on the page after the JavaScript has been executed.

For example you have a section on your page

```
example.com/page1#about
```

which makes an AJAX call.

In order to make this URL crawlable by Google you had to change this to

```
example.com/page1#!about
```

so that Google knows that this section needs to only fetch a HTML snapshot of the section and not the complete page.

However this syntax is deprecated by Google and you no longer have to change your links to `#!`. For complete details read this article: [AJAX Crawling (deprecated)](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=de).

Google now supports complete JavaScript crawling of pages. If your site is built heavily on JavaScript then follow this video series by Google: [Introducing a new JavaScript SEO video series](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/03/introducing-new-javascript-seo-video.html?m=1).